# Mac App Store is damaged error message

Tags: mac-app-store

I have an App that I'm submitting to the Mac App Store.  It code signs without any problems, producing a .pkg file as expected...

```
codesign -s "$app_cert" -f "$app_name.app"
codesign -d -vvvv "$app_name.app"
productbuild --component "$app_name.app" /Applications --sign "$installer_cert" "$app_name.pkg"
```

...and everything seems to work fine, no errors, everything checks out OK.  I then test install the App using the following...

```
sudo installer -store -pkg MyApp.pkg -target /
```

...everthing seems to go OK.  I then double-click on the App in my Applications folder and it asks me to enter my itunes account info.  I use the test user account that I set up in iTunes Connect and then I get this error:

```
"MyApp" is damaged and can’t be opened. Delete "MyApp" and download it again from the App Store.
```

What is really odd is that this is an update to MyApp.  The first time I submitted, everything worked fine.  It's only now that I'm seeing this problem, but I can't figure out what is wrong.  There are no errors in the Console logs.

I've triple checked and there is no other MyApp.app on my entire drive as this is known to cause issues.

Anyone know what is going on?  I've resign and packaged this App 10 times with no change.  I've tried installing from several different machines, same error.  Nothing significantly has changed in my build environment since the initial submission that work find.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The problem was that we had the app version number in two places - in the XCode project, and also hardwired in the receipt validation code; when we updated the receipt validation version to match the XCode project it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error message can appear even if your receipt validation code is correct, apparently because a caching issue can cause the test receipt to be downloaded with an incorrect version number.

In that case, restart the computer to clear up the caching issue, and run a clean build (or delete the test receipt from the app bundle) to obtain a new test receipt. See [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/798600) on the developer forums for additional comment.